# Suppress Bracket Syntax in TypeScript with SuppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors = true

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to refactor an array to use a more complex type.

It would be useful if this new type could be defined as to prevent the use of bracket notation.

Unfortunately, due to existing code, `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` is set in my **tsconfig**.  So I am looking for an explicit way to do this on a class by class basis.

e.g.

old code

```
const myArray: Object[] = [];
...
myArray[myNumber] = myObject;
```

new code

```
class CDoNotUseBrackets {
    myProperty: Object;
    // Add some code here to prevent usage of bracket notation
}

const myArray: CDoNotUseBrackets = new CDoNotUseBrackets();
...
myArray[myNumber] = myObject; // I want this to be marked as a type error
```

I have tried several things, e.g.

```
class CDoNotUseBrackets {
    myProperty: Object; // ERROR: Property 'myProperty' of type 'Object' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.ts(2411)
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

and reached partial success with

```
class CDoNotUseBrackets {
    myProperty: Object;
    [key: number]: undefined;
}

const mmk = new MultiKeyMap<string, string, string>();
mmk.set("a", "b", "c");
var x = 7;
mmk[x] = new Object(); // ERROR : Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
mmk["x"] = new Object(); // PASSES
```

but have been unable to find a way to make all bracket-notation access blow an error.

Comment: Types are a constraint on what values something can have, not a constraint on what syntax you can use to create those values. But it's also not clear what you mean by "bracket notation"; do you mean preventing additional properties other than those included in the type declaration?

Comment: Braket-notation as in "not dot notation", and yes, I want to prevent the addition of properties to my object.

Comment: When I use your sample code, without changing your `CDoNotUseBrackets` class, `myArray[myNumber] = myObject;` does give me a type error: *"No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'CDoNotUseBrackets'."*. What version of Typescript are you using, and what compiler options?

Comment: In Typescript you can define an object’s properties by creating a custom type (using `type` or `interface`), this prevents new properties being added that weren’t defined in the type. It doesn’t matter what kind of notation is used to add those properties. But it seems you want to allow adding new untyped properties at runtime as long as dot notation is used???

Comment: @kaya3 I am using TS 3.5.3, I see the `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,` is set in my tsconfig (big project with many devs, so I do not have full control).  **I updated the question to reflect this**.